# How to Get Message and Show it in Android Client from Java Socket Asyhncronous

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to build a android client that can get and show the message when the server send a new message. 
I use java socket for server.
and [this](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/async-servlet/async-servlets.html) is related tutorial that i have tried and it run well.
So i want to ask, how i connected the server to android client so i can get the message and show the message in my emulator?

Comment: The server does not connect, the Android device should connect to the server which accepts the connections in a well known port, like 5500 for example.

Comment: how i connected it, can u give me the way how to connected it